# Visual Studio 2010 / 2012 - Is there an eclipse-like Type completion?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Im new to visual studio and C# - and one thing in VS drives me crazy:

In eclipse you can start typing a Type-name, press CTRL-SPACE and it shows you types which match to the String you typed even if they´re not imported yet.

This is very useful specially if you´re new to the API and don´t know exact Type names etc.

I noticed, that VS offers type name completion ONLY in case the namespace has been imported in using section.

Is it possible to make it extend its search to all available namespaces?

Please do not recommend commercial tools like ReSharper because I´m currently willing to get used to VS "as it is" w/o paying lot of money for extensions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware the Eclipse-like functionality you describe is not available in visual studio as standard.  It, like many other nice things in Eclipse, is available as part of Resharper, a very large (commercial) plugin for Visual Studio.  By default it binds completing an un-imported class name to Alt-Shift-Space.

As a former Eclipse user, VS felt powerful but very clumsy until I added Resharper.  A particular relief is having control-T and control-shift-T available again - no more slowly meandering the Solution Explorer looking for where a former colleague has left a class.

Resharper is produced by JetBrains who also make IdeaJ, which I believe was an influence on Eclipse, so the similarities between the two are not a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

It searches in already used namespaces...
However, after you write class name correctly click **ctrl+dot** and it show you namespace like this.

[image]

Or Right click on the class name and than resolve. **RightClick>Resolve**

Comment: Well, this was what I knew, I was just wondering if there is a possibility wo search namespaces which are not currently used...? (Like eclipse does)